# Postgres incomplete startup packet error

Tags: postgresql, errors, error-log

I am attempting to install Postgres 9.3 on Ubuntu 14.04 and I am getting an irksome error on startup. Here's what I'm seeing:

```
$ sudo service postgresql restart
* Restarting PostgreSQL 9.3 database server
* Error: could not exec /usr/lib/postgresql/9.3/bin/pg_ctl /usr/lib/postgresql/9.3/bin/pg_ctl start -D /var/lib/postgresql/9.3/main -l /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-9.3-main.log -s -o  -c config_file="/etc/postgresql/9.3/main/postgresql.conf" : [fail]
```

So I checked the log file with this output:

```
 2015-01-05 21:50:05 EST LOG:  database system was shut down at 2015-01-05 21:50:03 EST
 2015-01-05 21:50:05 EST LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
 2015-01-05 21:50:05 EST LOG:  autovacuum launcher started
 2015-01-05 21:50:06 EST LOG:  incomplete startup packet
 2015-01-05 21:51:22 EST ERROR:  syntax error at or near "exit" at character 1
 2015-01-05 21:51:22 EST STATEMENT:  exit;
```

"Incomplete startup packet" seems to be the culprit but  I am having trouble finding info out there on what might be going on, so I thought I would ask. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

There are 3 different items in this question:

- *Incomplete startup packet* occuring at server start is inconsequential, you may ignore it. Read [Incomplete startup packet help needed](http://postgresql.nabble.com/Incomplete-startup-packet-help-needed-td5199030.html) (in pgsql-general mailing-list) for more.
- *syntax error at or near "exit" at character 1* means that a client issued `exit` as if it was an SQL statement.
- The *could not exec* error when issuing `service postgresql restart` looks like a serious installation problem but it's contradicted by the log entry `database system is ready to accept connections` meaning that the server started up just fine.

Comment: Your response "looks like a serious installation problem" prompted me to do some more research on how to entirely delete Postgres and reinstall. I found [this article](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2748607/how-to-thoroughly-purge-and-reinstall-postgresql-on-ubuntu) which was helpful in removing every trace of Postgres prior to reinstall and worked great.

Comment: one of the possible causes of "Incomplete startup packet" is when a TCP connection is made to the postgresql port 5432, and the immediately closed. This can happen when a monitoring program is configured to check the port, but not to run a SQL command.

Comment: Nicely spotted @TomH, that bit me today. Is there any other way to check that the database is accepting connections? MySQL has `mysqladmin --wait=30 ping`

Comment: @YarekT: [pg_isready](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pg-isready.html) - check the connection status of a PostgreSQL server

Answer (score -2):

Maybe your iptables are dropping packages on port 5432.
Consider adding the following rule to your iptables:

```
# sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 5432 -j ACCEPT
```