# Postgres seems to ignore listen_addresses setting

Tags: postgresql, configuration, pg-hba.conf

I'm trying to DISABLE remote client access on my Postgres 9.5.7 database (running Ubuntu 16.04).

I made what I thought are the correct changes (see below) to no avail. I can think of two reasons why my changes wouldn't work:

- I'm editing the wrong file
- I'm not restarting the service properly

I thought I ruled these out, but remote clients can still talk. So what am I missing?

Actually, what I'm trying to do is revert my changes that enabled remote client access on so I can capture those changes and re-apply them with our salt stack. Before I start running deployment tests via salt I want to know that remote access is disabled so that I can be confident that my salt stack is making the changes.

**Some data**

I'm starting postgres using the same config file I'm editing (`ps` output reformatted for readability)

```
postgres@testweb:~$ ps -eaf | grep bin/post
postgres [snip] /usr/lib/postgresql/9.5/bin/postgres 
                -D /var/lib/postgresql/9.5/main 
                -c config_file=/etc/postgresql/9.5/main/postgresql.conf
```

postgres is configured to listen on the localhost port only (this was '*' earlier)

```
postgres@testweb:~$ grep listen_addresses /etc/postgresql/9.5/main/postgresql.conf
listen_addresses = 'localhost'      # what IP address(es) to listen on;
```

Host-based auth is set to localhost. This shouldn't matter if I'm DISABLING access, correct? My understanding is that if `listen_addresses='localhost'` then remote client access will not work.

```
postgres@testweb:~$ grep ^host /etc/postgresql/9.5/main/pg_hba.conf
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
```

I'm editing the correct config files, yet listen_addresses claims `*`

```
postgres@testweb:~$ sql
psql (9.5.7)
Type "help" for help.

postgres=# show config_file;
           config_file
------------------------------------------
/etc/postgresql/9.5/main/postgresql.conf
(1 row)

postgres=# show hba_file;
               hba_file
--------------------------------------
/etc/postgresql/9.5/main/pg_hba.conf
(1 row)

postgres=# show listen_addresses;
 listen_addresses
------------------
*
```

Proof at the OS level that we're still listening on ALL interfaces (that is, that the `show list_addresses;` command is in effect.

```
postgres@testweb:~$ netstat -nlt | grep 5432
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5432            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::5432                 :::*                    LISTEN
```

I have a custom conf file in `conf.d`, but I'm unclear if it's being read, because I didn't touch this in order to allow remote client access. Regardless, it is set to what I want for now

```
postgres@testweb:~$ cat /etc/postgresql/9.5/main/conf.d/custom.conf
listen_addresses = 'localhost'
shared_buffers = 4011MB
work_mem = 320MB
maintenance_work_mem = 1018MB
effective_cache_size = 8022MB
shared_preload_libraries = 'pg_stat_statements'
```

No stray config files appear on the server

```
postgres@testweb:~$ locate postgresql.conf
/etc/postgresql/9.5/main/postgresql.conf
/etc/postgresql/9.5/main/postgresql.conf.bak
/usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/postgresql.conf
/usr/share/postgresql/9.5/postgresql.conf.sample

postgres@testweb:~$ locate pg_hba.conf
/etc/postgresql/9.5/main/pg_hba.conf
/usr/share/postgresql/9.5/pg_hba.conf.sample
```

I restart the postgres instance with `service postgresql restart` (I've even tried restarting the server (ugh) just to make sure. Still no luck. I've verified that if I execute `service postgresql stop` that my remote clients fail.

Obviously, in futzing around to ENABLE remote client access I must have tweaked something else; but for the life of me I cannot think of what it was. I have undone the changes I remember making (in the two conf files). I must have missed something ... but what?

**EDIT(s)**

per a comment, if I log in specifying the host, I see the same result (AFAIK, I never set the postgres user password, so I'm accessing as root).

```
root@testweb:~# sudo -u postgres -h localhost psql
psql (9.5.7)
Type "help" for help.

postgres=# show listen_addresses;
 listen_addresses
------------------
 *
(1 row)

postgres=# show config_file;
               config_file
------------------------------------------
 /etc/postgresql/9.5/main/postgresql.conf
(1 row)
```

Per another comment, here is the output after executing `service postgresql restart` ... seems clean (unsure about the last line ... [research](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/87636/23171) (thanks Daniel) inidicates that it's "inconsequential")

```
2017-07-18 17:43:16.440 MDT [4911] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2017-07-18 17:43:15 MDT
2017-07-18 17:43:16.444 MDT [4911] LOG:  MultiXact member wraparound protections are now enabled
2017-07-18 17:43:16.447 MDT [4910] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
2017-07-18 17:43:16.447 MDT [4915] LOG:  autovacuum launcher started
2017-07-18 17:43:16.848 MDT [4917] [unknown]@[unknown] LOG:  incomplete startup packet
```

Comment: Have you tried `psql -h localhost`, you *might* be connecting to another version of PostgreSQL, if you have more than one installed.

Comment: I tried that; I would have expected `ps` output to expose any other running instances, but it's worth double-checking

Comment: Is there any message in the log suggestion that the config file could not be read? [I doubt that PostgreSQL would start at all..]. Is there any possibility that the setting `listen_addresses = ...` appears *more than once* in the config file? Or that it is # commented out? From your exhaustive list, I think you've already checked and double-checked every reasonable thing... so I'm firing a bit at will

Comment: If `include_dir` is uncommented, there may be another stray `listen_address` in an alternate file. You may try `find /etc/postgresql -type f -exec grep listen_addresses {} \; -print` just in case. Also does changing other parameters work?

Comment: `include_dir` is uncommented; I included the contents of the only file in there `custom.conf` ... there is a `listen_addresses` in there, but it's set to `localhost`. I've removed that line just to be sure (hadn't thought of that before). Restarted, no changes : ( Great idea though.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Look at the `postgresql.auto.conf` file in your $PGDATA.

If someone uses the `ALTER SYSTEM` command to change the settings, you will find the value there.

`postgresql.auto.conf` is read after `postgresql.conf`and each setting put in this file overwrite those in `postgresql.conf`...

It's worth giving a look...

Comment: Argh! This was it ... as soon as I read this answer I remember attempting to fix my initial setup by executing tan `alter system` command (I had issues in my `pg_hba.conf`that needed resolving, and I later corrected these. Executing `ALTER SYSTEM RESET LISTEN_ADDRESSES` did the trick. Thanks!

Comment: I am trying to set the listen_addresses to * from localhost using command ALTER SYSTEM SET listen_addresses TO "*"; . But I am not able to change the pramater. Am I doing anythng wrong in this command;

Comment: Did you restart the server ? This parameter needs restart as mentionned in documentation (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-connection.html#RUNTIME-CONFIG-CONNECTION-SETTINGS)